# Can't find element text using XPATH with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I keep getting the following exception because I cannot find an element. I have tried everything from CSS Selectors to XPATH:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="content"]/div[9]/div"}

Here are screenshots of the structure of the HTML:

[image: HTML Code]

It is the highlights div at the end.

I tried:

```
net_sales = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#content > div.tbGrossSalesWithTax.s4 > div")

net_sales = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div[9]/div')
```

Is there a better way to highlight the element?

Comment: Posting code as images is not a best practice since makes the question not a [mcve].

Comment: if you tried everything, did everything throw errors? Because that CSS selector looks fine (even though it doesn't strictly _need_ that `>` in there)

Comment: @LMC the code is from a website, I am trying to scrape from.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah, I even did it without the > I am not sure why it is doing that. Should I post my complete code, maybe because the page is refreshing?

Comment: @beginner_coder1 you should post a minimum html snippet containing the relevant part. Nobody is going to type code from an image to try to solve the problem. Posting images of code goes against the chances of getting an answer :-)

Comment: At the least please show [mcve] where possible, and if you tried multiple things, also show the errors you got for each of those. You don't want people to guess at what's wrong: guesses are not answers =) (and as pointed out: [don't post pictures of code](/help/how-to-ask). Just post the code and talk about it in your post)

Comment: Looks like the usual default namespace issue. Search for "XPath default namespace". I don't know Selenium, so I don't know how to resolve the problem in your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If Content and tbGrossSalesWithTax are unique the the best way to do this is probably:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#content .tbGrossSalesWithTax div"));
```

This wouldn't be the most ideal way to do it but it is hard to see the best way without the full page structure or knowing what you are attempting to achieve. If the elements are not unique then it may be a little more complex but still should be manageable.

Comment: I tried this without the IWebElement, it's just hard to share the code given most of it is private information of the business. Let me try this to see if it works.